# Why the map function does not stop when we input multiple iterables with different length

Tags: python-3.x

I have read the documentation of the map function and realized that it can have input with multiple iterables. The document said that the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. Does it mean the map function will apply the function to each element in 2 iterables concurrently and stop when it finishes the shorter iterable? I have tried and relized that the map will apply the function to all elements in 2 iterables without any stop.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing passing a list of lists with passing multiple lists. In your case, you have passed only one list which contains both the `a` and `c` arrays, so the `map` function really only sees one overall iterable and it applies your function call to each of the two elements of the list (`a` and `c`). It appears that it doubled each element because you can perform element-wise operations on numpy arrays using normal operators.

Passing multiple iterables to the `map` function would be something like `map(double, a, c)` in which case, yes, it would stop when it finishes the shorter iterable. However, it does not individually `map` your function to each iterable, instead you would need to write a separate function to take two arguments at once as it iterates through both iterables at once, passing corresponding elements from both to your function, and stops when the shorter iterable has no more elements. Finally, this will return a *single* list containing the result of the function mapped to the pairs of corresponding elements

An example:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
c = np.array([6, 7])

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

print(list(map(add, a, c)) # [7, 9]
```

As you can see, this will stop after the shorter iterable has exhausted all elements

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However when I tried to pass map(double, a, c) it raises TypeError: double() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @ĐặngBáMinh yes, that's what I mentioned towards the end of my answer. If multiple iterables are passed, then an item from _each_ iterable is passed at once to your function. Since you are passing both `a` and `c` to the `map` function, the function you pass in (in this case, `double`) needs to be able to receive two arguments rather than one. An example would be writing a function `add` which takes two arguments `x` and `y` and returns their sum, then you could do `map(add, a, c)` which would return _one_ list of the sums of each of the corresponding elements from `a` and `c`

Comment: @ĐặngBáMinh I added an example to explain this a little better

Answer (score 1):

The `map` built-in functions takes the iterables in the form `*iterables`, thought this is not clearly obvious from the documentation page. You are currently only giving it one iterable: a list of `[a, c]`

It also states

> If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel.

This means if you pass multiple iterables, they are `zip`ped and those results are used as arguments, as seen here:

```py
>>> def printer(*args):
...     print(f'Got {len(args)} arguments:', ','.join(map(str, args)))
...
>>> list(map(printer, [[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]))
Got 1 arguments: [1, 2, 3]
Got 1 arguments: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> list(map(printer, [1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
Got 2 arguments: 1,5
Got 2 arguments: 2,4
Got 2 arguments: 3,3
```

I hope this clears up any confusion.